# difficulty getting ssl to work on tomcat7 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, tomcat7, server.xml

I am trying to get SSL to work, but I am having trouble. When I do it locally, everything works fine, but when I do it on my ubuntu server, the page does not open. I have created a keystore using the "$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA" method and have edited my server.xml file which I am pasting below.

Any help is very much appreciated.

```
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <!--
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  -->
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="11045" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->

    <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
         port="11045" SSLEnabled="true"
                 maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="password"
                 clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>    
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
   <!-- 
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" redirectPort="8443" />
   -->


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Is there any error message in catalina.out? Are you sure the port is not blocked by a firewall?

Comment: Thanks for your help David. The port is not blocked because when I use it without SSL it works fine.

Comment: What about catalina.out?

Comment: Catalina out does not show any related information.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
You are setting different port (11045)

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"   
               port="8443"   
               SSLEnabled="true"  
               scheme="https"   
               secure="true"  
               clientAuth="false"   
               sslProtocol="TLS"  

               keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore"  
               keystorePass="changeit"  
               />  

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->  
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: I actually need the application to work on port 11045 and that is the one the system admin opened.

Comment: yes, I have...port 11045 works fine with no SSL, but when I use that port for SSL it doesn't work.

Comment: but why are you redirecting to 8443?

Comment: I fixed that on my file, sorry. Let me paste latest version.
      <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="11045" />
 <Connector port="11045"     protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
                maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="tapestry"
                clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

Comment: <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="11045" /> and are you sure that it can find the keystoreFile="/full/path/to/tomcat.keystore? any log messages you are getting?

Comment: Nope :(. No log messages on Catalina.out

Comment: are you sure about root dir? usually default palce is user.home dir

Comment: When I make the keystone as sudo then the keystone is located in /root/ but when I create it as a normal user it is under home/username/

Comment: but can tomcat access root dir? does it have privileges?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: you can make it public by chmod 777 {folder}, but don't do it. dont run tomcat as root as well. just place the keystore in user's home dir and in server.xml point to that keystore.

Comment: hmm, the way things are working now, I have to "sudo service tomcat7 restart" to start tomcat else it says permission denied. I moved the keystore file to the home dir, but still no luck.

Comment: sorry mate, i don't have any other options. maybe start from scratch?(also maybe use different port just to see if ssl will work(8443))

Comment: Thats fine. Thank you VERY much for all your advice.